# doubly linked lists function c++ (homework)

Tags: c++

My professor gave us the code below to modify, which started as a linked list, and told us to make a doubly linked list. 
My `displayLast()` function only displays in the same order as `display()`, and while the `addEnd()` function gives no error, it does when trying to display the values. 
I want to get 'displayLast()' to display in reverse, then hopefully I can figure out the adding at the end on my own.

```
/*******************************
*  Week 2 lesson:              *
*   a simple LinkedList class  *
*******************************/

#include <iostream>
#include "LinkedList.h"

using namespace std;

/*
* Initializes the list to empty creating a dummy header node.
*/
LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    first = new Node;
    first->next = NULL;


}

/*
* Destructor. Deallocates all the nodes of the linked list,
* including the header node.
*/
LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
    Node *temp;

    while (first != NULL)
    {
        temp = first;
        first = first->next;
        delete temp;
    }
}

/*
* Determines whether the list is empty.
*
* Returns true if the list is empty, false otherwise.
*/
bool LinkedList::isEmpty()
{
    return first->next == NULL;
}

/*
* Prints the list elements.
*/
void LinkedList::display()
{
    Node * current = first->next;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        cout << current->info << " ";
        current = current->next;
    }

    cout << endl;
}
void LinkedList::displayLast()
{
    Node *current = last;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        cout << current->info << " ";
        current = current->prev;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

/*
* Adds the element x to the beginning of the list.
*
* x: element to be added to the list.
*/
void LinkedList::add(int x)
{
    Node *p = new Node;

    p->info = x;
    p->next = first->next;
    p->prev = last;
    first->next = p;
    last = p;
}
void LinkedList::addEnd(int x)
{
    Node *p = new Node;
    p->info = x;
    p->prev = last;
    last->next = p;
    last = p;
}


/*
* Removes the first occurrence of x from the list. If x is not found,
* the list remains unchanged.
*
* x: element to be removed from the list.
*/
void LinkedList::remove(int x)
{
    Node * old = first->next,
        *p = first;

    //Finding the address of the node before the one to be deleted
    bool found = false;
    while (old != NULL && !found)
    {
        if (old->info == x) found = true;
        else
        {
            p = old;
            old = p->next;
        }
    }

    //if x is in the list, remove it.
    if (found)
    {
        p->next = old->next;
        delete old;
    }
}
```

Here is the . file:

```
class LinkedList
{
public:
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();
    bool isEmpty();
    void display();
    void add(int);
    void remove(int);
    void addEnd(int);
    void displayLast();

private:
    Node * first;   //pointer to header (dummy) node
    Node *last;
};
```

Comment: Not yet relevant but `NULL` is an anachronism in C++; do please use `nullptr` instead.

Comment: In future please keep your questions brief and to the point.

Comment: A [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) requires the code in `LinkedList.h`, too.

Comment: I apologize...   and I will keep it short in the future...

Comment: It's not too late @JamesH: you can always edit your question.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Edited.  I hope that is a little better.  The main part I'm trying to figure first is display in reverse.  It displays the same as the regular display.  I think if I can figure that part out I can dissect it and figure out the add at end.

Comment: In the LinkedList constructor, when you initialize all of LinkedList's member variables, did you initialize `last`?